# Simulating the rise and fall of the Stock Market java

Tags: java, oop

So I'm trying to write a program that stimulates the rise and fall of the Stock market 5 times.The user inputs a value to create a new Stock Market Object then with the value from the user, the stock market either is a bust(decrease) or a boom( increase). The issue I'm having is passing the value to each if statement with the change within the loop.When I run the program, It uses the same value I entered instead of using the value that was created after calling boom or bust. I'm thinking I should create a value outside the loop that holds it but I'm not sure how to do that with the user input.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a Starting Market Value:");
        double mv = in.nextDouble();
        StockMarket u = new StockMarket(mv);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            System.out.println("Boom (1) or Bust(2)? ");
            int t = in.nextInt();

            if (t == 1) {
                System.out.println("Enter a percentage of increase as a decimal ( eg .5 ):");
                double r = in.nextDouble();
                if (t == 1) {
                    double e = u.boom(r);
                    System.out.println("The Stock Market is now at: " + e);
                }
            } else if (t == 2) {
                System.out.println("Enter number of points lost:");
                double l = in.nextDouble();

                if (t == 2) {
                    double f = u.bust(l);
                    System.out.println("The Stock Market is now at: " + f);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Below is the class

```
public class StockMarket {

//Instance Variable Points

    private double Points;

// Default no Argument Constructor

    public StockMarket(){

        this(0.0);
    }
// Constructor #2

    public StockMarket(double Points){

        this.Points = Points;
    }

//
    public double getPoint(){


        return Points;

    }

    public double boom(double x){

       x = Points * (1 + x);
        return x;
   }

   public double bust( double h){

        h = Points - h;
        return h;
   }

}
```

Comment: You're right that you need a variable outside the loop to hold the changing current stock market level.  And in fact you _already have_ the perfect candidate: the `Point` attribute of the `StockMarket` object.  The `boom()` or `bust()` methods should not only compute the new stock market level based on the current `Point` and the given value, they should also update `Point` with the new level.

Comment: So does that mean I should return both newly created point and and value of the methods or do i just return the value of the method and eg. Point += x

Comment: Well, you can't return _two_ values at once.  You'd  want `boom()` and `bust()` to continue returning the same results they do now;   but also save that result into `Point` before returning.

Comment: Gotcha Thanks for the help @KevinAnderson. How does my code look, I feel like i should clean it up, but everything is working now lol

Comment: Aside from a few spurious blank lines I'd say your code is reasonably attractive; most importantly it's well indented, which helps readability more than just about anything.  I'd suggest avoiding blank lines 1) _after_ a "{"; 2) _before_ a "}"; and 3)  between a comment and the thing it is commenting upon. Also avoid more than one blank line in a row.  Also, it is a generally accepted convention that variable, field, and method names start with a lowercase letter", so I'd suggest renaming `Point` to `point`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson thanks for the help and suggestions. I've been struggling with that for a little while.